# xml quote attribute value in tcl

Tags: tcl

How can I "convert" non valid `xml` (i.e. some attrbutes not quoted) to be a valid xml, i.e. convert all `a=b` attribute to be `a="b"`.

For example for such xml file:

```
<Top>
<Name name='name' />
<Group number=1>
<Member name='name1' test='test1' l=100/>
</Group>
</Top>
```

Desire output will be:

```
<Top>
<Name name='name' />
<Group number="1">
<Member name='name1' test='test1' l="100"/>
</Group>
</Top>"
```

I know about `tdom` package, which has `-html` option. But the package which I should use is `dom`, for which the xml file attribute must be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid XML document, so we can't use an XML processor like tDOM for this. Instead, we have to do something nasty with regular expressions and hope for the best:

```
set inputDocument "…"

regsub -all {(\w+)=(\w+)} $inputDocument {\1="\2"} outputDocument

puts $outputDocument
```

This isn't very good to be honest, but it will do the right thing in your case. It would be possible to put more effort in and ensure that the transformation is only applied within elements and not in bodies as well, but if it's good enough for your real data then it's good enough. (Getting such transformations right is quite hard since the input document is *not* XML; who knows what other nasties could be lying in wait inside in general?)